# MySQL: ceasing to use a Scheme (Database)?

Tags: mysql

How do I stop using a database?

To start mysql, you can use:

```
mysql -u root -pXXXX<ENTER>
```

At this time, no database is selected. We'll call this

*state 1*

To select (or use) a database:

```
use "MyDB";
.....My operations or queries
```

Now, I want to return to *state 1* (without any database selected). How I can do that? I can select another database, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 7):

What you are asking for is not possible. The only way to return to that state is to disconnect and then reconnect.

If you are just looking to switch away from your current db, you can switch to a system database, such as the internal "mysql" database:

```
use mysql
```

Or you could create an empty database and use that:

```
create database empty;
use empty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create database empty;
use empty;
drop database empty;
```

This should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try `prompt`.

From the MySQL manual:

> Reconfigure the mysql prompt to the given string. The special
>   character sequences that can be used in the prompt are described later
>   in this section.
>        If you specify the `prompt` command with no argument, mysql resets the prompt to the default of `mysql>`.

Comment: I love that feature, but it's not relevant to this question.

Comment: What does `prompt` with no argument do then? I read the docs and interpreted it as resetting the command line tool to how it is after initially running `mysql`?

Answer (score -1):

[Ike Walker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13146930) is on the right track me thinks.

Create a swap space, *or* you could just halt the server (stop the process) and restart it I suppose. That defeats the purpose of the server—but it would for sure wind up where you want it with no database in 'use'.

I'm certain you know this, but I mention here just in case. You never know. Someone might not know it is possible to do this.